# Cross-domain tracking and method="get"

Tags: google-analytics

As per [Tracking Code: Domains and Directories](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/methods/gaJSApiDomainDirectory#_gat.GA_Tracker_._linkByPost), the _linkByPost() method works with `method="post"` only.

Is there a way to allow for cross-domain tracking using `method="get"`? I need to submit a form to an external service, which does not allow HTTP POST.

Comment: Haven't work with the old code for quite some time, but IIRC it was possible to write a js function that uses _getLinkerUrl() to obtain an url with cross domain parameters and set it dynamically as form action. https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/methods/gaJSApiDomainDirectory#_getlinkerurl

Comment: I would bet analytics.js supports it.  you should really switch to using that.